# Levels and Menus with Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a school project to write a game in Python using pygame. I chose to make a turret defense game, and I want to have multiple levels as well as a menu between them where I can upgrade the turret.

The game would ideally function similarly to Turret Defense 2 (http://www.crazymonkeygames.com/Turret-Defense-2.html)

Here is my mainloop:

```
def gen_enemies(enemies, sprites, lvl):
        if lvl < 10:
            times = [t for t in range(1, 1000*lvl)]
            for j in range(10*lvl):
                spawn_time = random.choice(times)
                s = Soldier(screen, spawn_time)
                enemies.add(s)
                sprites.add(s)

    done = False
    playing = True
    level = 1

    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    while not done:

            gen_enemies(enemies, all_sprites, level)

            while playing:

            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    done = True
                    playing = False

                '''key functions for shooting and moving the turret'''

            '''creating bullets'''

            t.move()        

            screen.fill(WHITE)

            '''Here, I move bad guys with some other code'''

            for b in bullets:
                b.update()
                if b.rect.x > screen_width or b.rect.y > screen_height:
                    b.kill()
                enemy_hits = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(b, enemies, False)
                if len(enemy_hits) != 0:
                    enemy_hits[0].health -= 10
                    b.kill()
                    if enemy_hits[0].health == 0:
                        kills.append(enemy_hits[0])
                        enemy_hits[0].kill()
                        score += enemy_hits[0].score

        if len(kills) == 10*level:
            '''Takes me out of playing loop (so I can go to menu)'''
            frame = 0
            playing = False

        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        t.draw()

        pygame.display.flip()
        frame += 1
        clock.tick(100)

    '''This is where I want to go to a menu'''

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                print("BEGIN")
                space_down = False
                level += 1
                playing = True

pygame.quit()
```

The game runs perfectly for the first level. I kill 10 bad guys and the game leaves the playing loop. I have not built a menu yet, but when I hit the return key to advance a level, the game suddenly generates infinite enemies. Why is this?

I'm working with Python 3.5.1 on Mac